# Power monitoring home electricity supply - No power generation yet power reverses direction at set times

Tags: power, mains

Setup:

My friends house.

The house has Economy 7 (UK tariff) which has a single incoming supply but the meter then seperates it into "Day" and "Night" conductors.

They have been getting bills that state they have used ca. 60-70 kWh a day (two-bedroom, well-insulated home), so I have installed a power monitoring system that uses CTs clamped over the two conductors and stores the data which I can then view on a web interface.

I monitored the first week of data and saw nothing unsual apart from that they were typically using ca. 5 kWh in the day and ca. 10 kWh in the night (Day is classed as 8AM to 8PM and night 8PM to 8AM)

The system is made by a [homebrewer in the USA](https://github.com/David00/rpi-power-monitor/).

Generally this system was made for people who generate power and want to monitor production, but in this case there is no solar/wind.

It has only been running for about 3 weeks, but I am seeing negative power output come on at 12.30AM and off at 4.30AM. I know that the occupants are asleep by then; I can see it in the graphs.

I am absolutely positive the CTS are on the right way, I have calibrated it using a pure resistive load and checked the power factor correction. The calibration procedure is 'close enough', but I am seeing varying negative powers of ca. 2.5 to 6.5 kW :O

What on earth could be going on here - I suspected a possible electricity theft, but am baffled by how it goes negative.

Any help would be appreciated and I know this is a bit of an odd question.

Comment: *The system is made by a hombrewer in USA* - LOL. I'd say it has some integer overflow somewhere turning numbers to negative. Or there is some timer wrap-around, turning some time period negative and then is used in the calculation.

Comment: I had Economy 7 in the 80s. It had a dual-rate meter but only one set of wiring to the house. Appliances needed their own timers to benefit from the night rate. There was an older system, known as the white meter, which had, unsurprisingly, a white meter and a contactor with a separate set of wiring to the night rate appliances, typically storage heaters. One set of my grandparents had this in their 60s home. Does the 00:30 to 04:30 period correspond to when your friends are using their night-rate appliances? Can you add a photo of their meter, etc & the CTs?

Comment: What consumption does their electricity meter record? Does it match the 5+10 kWh from your metering system or does it match the 60-70 kWh they are being billed for? Does the meter number on the electricity bill match the number on the actual meter? Is this an all-electric household, as expected for E7, or do they use another fuel for heating.

Answer (score 1):

IMAGES ARE MISSING OF THE GRAPH OUTPUT - If you want the images let me know.

Electricity Usage and Analysis of Economy7 at a ClwydAlyn Association Residence

Author: Paul Sullivan (BSc Comp. Sci)
Preface
This document is an analysis of a the electricity consumption of a two bedroom semi detached property rented by two adults.

It is written with the intent of highlighting how poor understanding of certain electricity tariffs and home wiring and appliances can lead to residents being forced into fuel poverty or heavy debt.

In the UK there are an estimated two million homes with dual tariff meters and it is not unreasonable to assume there are a high proportion of these users who, unwittingly, are being heavily penalised.
Introduction
I was approached by a family who could not understand why they were having to pay c. £5-600 per month on electricity. They could not understand how, when they seemingly were powering on heaters, immersion heaters so infrequently, that their house was cold.

They had been in contact many times with their supplier British Gas asking them to explain how this was possible and essentially were told the readings were correct so they had to pay. They also asked that a smart meter be installed but were told it could not due to how the current meter was wired to the home.

After some twelve months of complaining and getting nowhere with BG I took it upon myself to try figure out what was going on. At first I had a few ideas as to the probable cause: theft, meter fault, appliance fault, high usage or high unit rates.

For those (like me) who have never had a dual tariff meter a short explanation.

Economy7 is a quite well known dual tariff in the UK although there are others. It is sold on the basis that if you use most of your electricity in the night then you get a lower price per unit (kWh) between 12.30AM and 7.30AM (known as the NIGHT rate) and a much higher rate on during the other hours (DAY rate).

In terms of the meters installation some meters perform this switch over on a single conductor entering the house but in this case the meter, a “Horstmann Radio Telemeter Series K”, takes a single mains supply, splits this into two circuits (with two conductors exiting the unit), monitors both for power usage and gives a break down of units used on the DAY and NIGHT circuits. These conductors are then taken into the consumer units and split throughout the house with certain appliances, such as storage heaters, immersion tanks and other appliances deemed suitable to use the NIGHT rate wired in parallel. If they were only connected to the NIGHT circuit they could not be used during the day.
Monitoring Equipment
In order that we could start to understand where the energy was being used a system was installed that monitored both of the conductors (DAY and NIGHT) simultaneously and recorded the relevant powers, power factors and voltages.

The system involved clamping current transformers around both cables rated to the maximum load (100A) each of these were rated for. These current transformers (CT) then were monitored through and analogue to digital converter by a minicomputer (Raspberry PI running Linux). This Pi was also running a web server which was configured so as to give remote access to the data in graph form using Grafana.

You can read about the whole system, its setup and calibration at the link below:

https://github.com/David00/rpi-power-monitor

Data Collection and Initial Observations
Monitoring took place from the 14th January 2023 until present (as of 25th February 2023)

During the installation I also took note of many of the behaviours of the family appliance usage. I noted that every switch in the home was off at the wall, including wall heaters, immersion tank etc. The house was noticeably cold.

They explained to me that they were out working most of the weekdays and only put one wall heater on “Boost” mode for one hour down stairs and their bedroom heater on “Boost” for one hour when they were about to go to bed if required. If they needed hot water, turning on the immersion heater for ten minutes would be enough to last all night and was still warm in the morning.

Within the home there were five wall heaters, one immersion tank, an electric range, fridge freezer, power shower, two modest 40 inch LED televisions, LED lighting throughout and various other trivial appliances.

We will look at these appliances in more detail later.

Once the system was installed the household were left to their own devices until a reasonable amount of data had been recorded and we could start to analyse what was going on.
Identifying the problem

Verifying the Horstmann meter readings were correct was relatively straightforward to achieve. As a simple initial test we attached a purely resistive load (2kW heater) left it on for one hour and made sure the Horstmann meter recorded two units. We also noted meter readings at the time of installation and using the collected data later to correlate the two were reading accurately together – there is a minor 3% difference but is perfectly acceptable for our purposes.

We then turned our eyes to the gathered data (if you do not like graphs I will summarise later). The green trace are the DAY conductors data and the yellow is the NIGHT conductors data. Graph 1 is instantaneous power, graph 2 is power factor (don't worry about this one too much), graph 3 is a sum of data on each conductor over the day and the last graph is the sum cost of this household in electricity (based on the household tariff rates of £0.52 kWh DAY /  £0.17 kWh NIGHT)

At first we were confused. On the 18th of January a load started (see the yellow trace) coming on at night at 12.30 when apparently all the heaters etc. were off at the wall and we suspected theft...

After some time what was happening became apparent. One of the storage heaters in the home was turning on and charging up. Each of the wall heaters is a storage heater (which stores heat by heating bricks up inside itself and then it is supposed to discharge this heat through the following day. Next to each storage heater are two switches (named peak and off-peak) and if these are incorrectly set, the storage heater will charge overnight but then NOT output the heat.

To add insult to injury, when the family returned home and pressed the “Boost button” to get warm, even if their was heat stored in the unit from charging on the lower tariff, the unit would draw power from the DAY conductor...

So by turning everything off at the wall to save money they were in fact not utilising the dual meter correctly and it cost them even more.

I also noted that, due to the wiring in the house and how the appliances work when set in certain modes, even though heaters were left on overnight they would draw from the more expensive DAY tariff even though they were within the 12.30-7.30 time period. Note the yellow trace and the green trace – this is two heaters, one in the correct mode charging up overnight (and then not  being used) with another storage heater in the wrong mode (or depleted) accidentally being left on overnight on the 17/18th January.

I then started noticing the large spikes and wondered what on earth could be drawing so much power. It did not take long to find the culprit – power shower.

The residents had a 9.5kW power shower installed so they did not have to use the immersion heater. This power shower on its hottest settings would draw the full 9.5kW power (other settings were 3 and 5kW) meaning that, as was observed a 30 minute shower was taken that would be using 10p/minute.

It was later seen that if the immersion storage was used correctly they could heat the water up so that they had hot water (which could have been used for showering) for a fraction of the cost.

Unfortunately though it appears that either there is a setting on the immersion heater that incorrectly uses the DAY conductor even though it is on during the correct period or it has not been wired to the correct circuit within the home wiring.

Another implication of this wiring system is that, even if you did use all your electricity between 12.30AM and 7.30AM, if the appliance itself is not wired on the correct circuit or incorrectly configured the resident will always pay the higher tariff.

Correcting the Problem

Once we had identified the root cause of the problem I told the residents that they should use the wall heaters in the home on a certain setting (“comfort mode”) which kept their home warm and cost less which they started doing and indeed the costs did come down:

However, due to the extremely punitive cost of the DAY rate you would have to run at 50% power usage on the NIGHT tariff just to achieve the current energy price cap of 34.5p /kWh.

There are a lot of measures that could be undertaken to optimise this household to achieve reasonable running costs such as:

Configure the immersion heater to draw power from the NIGHT tariff
Remove the power shower and install mixer taps to draw from the immersion tank
Make sure power hungry appliances are used on the correct circuit at the correct times

However, without very careful understanding of how the house is wired, some of these are beyond the ability of most households.

Ideally if a meter was available with a single output conductor could be installed then this use of the correct tariff would resolve a large portion of the issue alongside education of the user as to how to correctly use appliances to maximise the saving.

The only other option is to move from dual tariff to single tariff. In this case British Gas never offered the option to these residents saying that the meter could not be changed.
Electricity Provider Responsibility

It will have been apparent to (in this case) British Gas that the dual tariff was not being used correctly in this property from the meter readings.

It would be interesting to know what they are required to tell customers who are on dual tariff meters that clearly are not using their tariff correctly.

What is the cost?

The residents last bill (2nd Jan - 23rd Feb) - £1,065 (including 5% VAT and standing charge).

Comment: Storage heater '“Boost button” [draws] power from the DAY conductor' That's what it does. If the householder underestimated the heat required for a day and left the input control too low, or uses it up too quickly with an excessive output setting, and the heater runs out of stored heat the boost button allows immediate heating on the day rate. It's more expensive but at least they have heat. An explanation with video of storage heater operation can be found [here](https://www.cse.org.uk/advice/advice-and-support/night-storage-heaters).

Comment: "Configure the immersion heater to draw power from the NIGHT tariff" That might involve replacing the on-off wall switch with an immersion heater timer. Make sure the contact rating is adequate for the heater. Get an electrician to fit one if necessary.

Comment: 'the meter, a “Horstmann Radio Telemeter Series K”, splits [the supply] into two circuits' [This thread](https://community.bulb.co.uk/t/horstmann-radio-telemeter-series-k-meter-reading/45461) suggests the second circuit is for the storage heaters (e.g. the August post). That's a variation on normal E7 wiring but matches your description of peak and off-peak switches by the heaters (both need to be on). [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvI40T4w4ck) also describes this and shows how to display readings (though rate 3 won't be free for this household).

Comment: "move from dual tariff to single tariff" Running an all-electric home on a single tariff will be expensive. It will be better to try to tune the use of E7 by moving the heating load (storage heaters and immersion heater) onto night rate. A 30 min 9.5 kW electric shower will cost £2.47 a go so using water from the (night rate) immersion heater will be cheaper, as will having much shorter showers.

Comment: "the immersion heater that incorrectly uses the DAY conductor" The immersion heater is probably connected to the general household wiring that gets switched between day and night rates on the meter. You can verify this by switching the heater on for known periods during the day and night periods and confirm that the relevant meter readings increase correspondingly. If so, the heater is wired correctly but you need to fit an immersion heater timer to allow convenient use (no-one wants to get up at 4 am for cheap hot water).

Answer (score 0):

Is the software assuming that one CT is measuring generation, rather than import, and so the polarity is the wrong way round on that one?  A system for monitoring a local generation system would typically have one CT on the line from the solar or wind inverter, and one on the supply meter tails.

Aside: The Economy 7 definition of "Night" and "Day" doesn't match the one you're using.  E7 has 7 hours of night, and 17 hours of day.

Comment: Hi Simon,

Thanks for your reply and to answer your questions:

There is no power generation. The CT around DAY and NIGHT conductors were corrected for polarity shortly after installation.

The outcome of the investigation is that on meters with dual conductors exiting the meter, dependent on wiring and appliance configuration, there can be misattribution of energy consumed on the night tariff to the day. No shit.

I will post my observations after this.